# How to host .net core grpc server on IIS and docker

Tags: iis, .net-core, grpc

How should I host my .net core 5 gRPC server on IIS and docker?
I tried with windows server 2016 and gRPC works totally fine on my IIS express but I can't host it on IIS (I tries using a self-signed certificate on IIS)

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, usually create a grpc client and server in asp.net core, and then publish asp.net core to iis, what do you mean?

Comment: Ofc I tried to publish but I can’t connect to my grpc server when it’s on IIS

Comment: What steps did you try? did you get any error messages?

Comment: FYI GRPC over HTTP2 in IIS works only on Windows Server 2022, anything older would have to use GrpcWeb, furthermore HTTP2 on IIS is supported only on SSL connections.